# Ошибка FATAL: no indexes found in config file 'C:\sphinx\sphinx.conf.in'

Tags: windows, битрикс, sphinx

Скажите, пожалуйста, где моя ошибка.
вот файл логов прилагается.

```
#
# Minimal Sphinx configuration for Bitrix
#
searchd
{
    listen          = 9312
    listen          = 9306:mysql41
    log         = C:/Sphinx/log/searchd.log   
    query_log       = C:/Sphinx/log/query.log 
    read_timeout        = 5
    max_children        = 30
    pid_file        = C:/Sphinx/log/searchd.pid 
    max_matches     = 1000
    seamless_rotate     = 1
    preopen_indexes     = 1
    unlink_old      = 1
    workers         = threads # for RT to work
    binlog_path     =  C:/Sphinx/data/  
    binlog_max_log_size     = 512M
    binlog_flush        = 2
    rt_flush_period     = 3600
}

indexer
{
    lemmatizer_cache    = 128M
}


index bitrix
{
    #main settings
        type = rt
        source = bitrix 
        path = C:/Sphinx/data/bitrix
        docinfo = inline
    #choose appropriate type of morphology to use
        #morphology = lemmatize_ru_all, lemmatize_en_all, lemmatize_de_all, stem_enru
        morphology = stem_enru, soundex
    #these settings are used by bitrix:search.title component
        dict = keywords
        prefix_fields = title
        infix_fields=
        min_prefix_len = 2
        enable_star = 1
    #all fields must be defined exactly as followed
        rt_field = title
        rt_field = body
        rt_attr_uint = module_id
        rt_attr_string = module
        rt_attr_uint = item_id
        rt_attr_string = item
        rt_attr_uint = param1_id
        rt_attr_string = param1
        rt_attr_uint = param2_id
        rt_attr_string = param2
        rt_attr_timestamp = date_change
        rt_attr_timestamp = date_to
        rt_attr_timestamp = date_from
        rt_attr_uint = custom_rank
        rt_attr_multi = tags
        rt_attr_multi = right
        rt_attr_multi = site
        rt_attr_multi = param
    #depends on settings of your site
        # uncomment for single byte character set
        #charset_type = sbcs
        # uncomment for UTF character set
        charset_type = utf-8
}

common{
    lemmatizer_base = C:/Sphinx/dicts/  # lemmatizer_base в Sphinx 2.2.1+ располагается в секции common
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша ошибка в том, что вы запускаете indexer, в то время как у вас в конфиге есть только один RealTime индекс, который не работает через indexer. Чтобы добавить в него данные нужно выполнять команды вставки данных.

Comment: Добрый день, какие именно команды вставки?... Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: INSERT или REPLACE